# AutomaticDimensions not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I want the cell to stretch to fit the content in the label.

Class:

```
class TestTableController: UITableViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var nameField: HoshiTextField!

  @IBOutlet weak var requestButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {//<- only for this row
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
  }


  @IBAction func requestButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Constraints:

[image]

[image]

(superview is the contentView, I double checked that)

Result (the cell is the lorem ipsum):

[image]

Number of lines set to zero:

[image]

Edit: Solved. Changed absolutely nothing, did a new build without even cleaning and now it works... =.=

Comment: You need to set numberOfLines = 0 for label, which should expend.

Comment: it's already set to 0, forgot to write that. Will update the question.

Comment: Take `contraints` from all side , this will work for u

Comment: Solved, check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Changed absolutely nothing, did a new build without even cleaning and now it works... =.=

Answer (score 0):

Set the text type to attributed[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
func tableView(UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt: IndexPath)
```

Give some random value. It should work.